# Extract record from array

Tags: jquery, html

I have a sorted array contains fixed length data. The array is as follow,

```
var samplearray = [12122013sample2,
                   10122013sample1,
                   12122013sam   1.5
                  ];
```

From this array I want to get the records matched to "12122013". That is, the following records should be returned:

```
                   12122013sample2
                   12122013sam   1.5
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem, but here's a tip : use `YYYYMMDD` format instead of `DDMMYYYY`, then you'll be able to sort results by date easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function searchInArray(what, where) {    
    var results = [];
    var regexp = new RegExp(what);
    for (var i=0;i<where.length; i++) {
       if (regexp.test(where[i]) ) results.push(where[i]);
    }
    return results.length>0 ? results : false;
}
```

It returns an array of matching elements or false if no match found.
The what parameter can be a string or a regexp pattern.

http://jsfiddle.net/gnYXJ/

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable reply. Can you implement the same concept without case sensitivity.

Comment: add the i flag. For exemple if you are looking for "sample" without case sensivity, use var results = searchInArray(/sample/i, yourarray);